# Getting MenuItem in onCreate

Tags: android, menuitem, oncreate

When I'm trying to edit a MenuItem into a Progressbar (when downloading some stuff in the background of my app) it work well, but sometimes(after a check in the onCreate of my MainActivity) I wanna download something as well.

So the problem is when I start trying to edit the MenuItem into a Progressbar in my onCreate, the MenuItem isn't created yet, so I can't edit it into a Progressbar.

Does anybody know how I can fix this problem, so I can edit my MenuItem in the onCreate of my activity?

Thank you!

Comment: why no answer!? same problem here.